# Can we run multiple marker in parallel?

Tags: pytest, pytest-xdist, pytest-markers

I have a python script and say I have 10 test cases in it. 5 are part of marker1 and another 5 are part of marker2. I want to start 2 threads in parallel so marker1 tests can run in 1 thread and marker2 tests can run in another. And my execution time is reduced.

If the resolution is not possible with marker then please suggest how can I run 5 linked tests in parallel and another 5 in parallel.

Comment: If you can put the related tests into separate test classes (or test modules), you could use `--dist=loadscope` - in this case xdist will put them into separate threads.

Comment: Thanks MrBean Bremer.